NVM 18.18.0 - How to add npm environment variable on a server
I'm trying to update nodejs on a server from version 18.15.0 to 18.18.0, for security reason there is no internet access on the server and I should do nvm install 18.18.0 but is not possible and got de nodejs version 18.18.0 from my pc and copy /past it on the c:\program files\nodejs shortcut folder.
I tried different ways to add the environment variable but I get the following error:
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

If I add the full path C:\Users\tfsbuildservice\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.18.0 it will be linked to that nodejs version but I'm not sur if it correct.
Ho to add manually the npm environment variable like if it was added automatically by using nvm install 18.18.0 please ?
Shoul I add it in a npm variable or/and in the path variable?
